# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can only assign users to permission set groups that have the "Updated" status

Tags: apex, unit-test, permission-sets, permission-set-groups

I'm struggling to assign a mocked permission set group in a test class.
The test class fails because of the following error:

```
INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, You can only assign users to permission set groups that have the "Updated" status.
```

This is the apex test class:

```
@isTest
private class UserPermissionControllerTest  {

   private static User createUserPermissionDataModel() {
       //permission set
       PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(
           Name = 'TestPermissionSet',
           Label = 'Test Permission Set'
       );
       insert ps;

       //permission set group
       PermissionSetGroup psg = new PermissionSetGroup(
           DeveloperName = 'TestPermissionSetGroup',
           MasterLabel = 'Test Permission Set Group'
           //Status = 'Updated'
       );
       insert psg;
       //permission set for group
       PermissionSet ps2 = new PermissionSet(
           Name = 'TestPermissionSetForGroup',
           Label = 'Test Permission Set For Group'
       );
       insert ps2;
       //permission set group component
       PermissionSetGroupComponent  psgc = new PermissionSetGroupComponent(
           PermissionSetGroupId = psg.Id,
           PermissionSetId = ps2.Id
       );
       insert psgc;

       //role
        UserRole role = new UserRole(
           Name = 'Developer',
           DeveloperName = 'Developer',
           CaseAccessForAccountOwner = 'Edit',
           OpportunityAccessForAccountOwner = 'Edit'
       );
       insert role;

       //user
       User permUser = new User(   
           FirstName = 'Test',
           LastName = 'User',
           Username = 'test.user@mock.de',
           Email = 'test.user@mock.de',
           Alias = 'testuser',
           TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Berlin',
           LocaleSidKey =  'en_US',
           LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
           EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
           profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id,
           UserRoleId = role.Id
       );
       insert permUser;
       //permission set assignment
       PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(
           AssigneeId = permUser.Id,
           PermissionSetId = ps.Id
       );
       insert psa;
       //permission set group assignment
       PermissionSetAssignment psga = new PermissionSetAssignment(
           AssigneeId = permUser.Id,
           PermissionSetGroupId = psg.Id
       );
       insert psga;
       
       return permUser;
   }
}
```

The status of the permission set group is null when I log the field. I don't know how to fix this issue and didn't find anything online that would point me to the right direction. Any help is highly appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

Added a test method that uses the method "createUserPermissionDataModel()" for additional input:

```
@isTest
private static void testGetUserPerm() {
    Test.startTest();
        User permUser = createUserPermissionDataModel();
        List<PermissionHelper.PermInfos> permInfos = UserPermissionController.getUserPerm(permUser.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, permInfos);
}
```

Comment: Try using a `Test.startTest`/`Test.stopTest` pair around the permission set creation, with the assignment outside that block.

Comment: @PhilW I already use the test pair in my other methods that make use of the initial method. I added a method for reference.

Comment: Is the perm set assignment itself in the start/stop block, or after it?

Comment: @PhilW I call the "createUserPermissionDataModel()" method inside the test block so it's inside it

Comment: Try splitting it like I said in my first comment.

Comment: @PhilW I split it and put the permission set assignment outside the block but still get the same error

Comment: Does this answer your question?  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/350326/deployment-fails-with-invalid-cross-reference-key-you-can-only-assign-users-to

Comment: @NickCook No, the question in the thread uses an actual permission set group from an org not mocked. I'm triyng to mock up a permission set group and assign assign it to a test user.

Comment: I seem to recall when I was doing my own testmethods that it was impossible to mock a PSG that you could assign a user to as I got the same error you did - which was why I used an existing PSG

Comment: @cropredy a co-worker looked over my problem and fixed it for me. The problem for me was that the PSG status changed to 'Outdated' after inserting the PSG-Component and second PS. I'm gonna post the working code as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem for me was that the status of the permission set group (PSG) changed after adding the PSG-Component and second Permission Set. I had to assign the PSG first before inserting new components. This fixed my problem:

```
//create user with permissions
public static User createUserPermissionDataModel() {
    //permission set
    PermissionSet ps = new PermissionSet(
         Name = 'TestPermissionSet',
         Label = 'Test Permission Set'
    );
    insert ps;
    //permission set group
    PermissionSetGroup psg = new PermissionSetGroup(
        DeveloperName = 'TestPermissionSetGroup',
        MasterLabel = 'Test Permission Set Group'
    );
    insert psg;
    //role
    UserRole role = new UserRole(
         Name = 'Developer',
         DeveloperName = 'Developer',
         CaseAccessForAccountOwner = 'Edit',
         OpportunityAccessForAccountOwner = 'Edit'
    );
    insert role;
    //user
    User permUser = new User(
         FirstName = 'test',
         LastName = 'user',
         Username = 'test.user@mock.de',
         Email = 'test.user@mock.de',
         Alias = 'testuser',
         TimeZoneSidKey = 'Europe/Berlin',
         LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
         LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
         EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
         profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'].Id,
         UserRoleId = role.Id
    );
    insert permUser;
    //permission set group assignment
    PermissionSetAssignment psga = new PermissionSetAssignment(
         AssigneeId = permUser.Id,
         PermissionSetGroupId = psg.Id
    );
    insert psga;
    
    //permission set for group
    PermissionSet ps2 = new PermissionSet(
        Name = 'TestPermissionSetForGroup',
        Label = 'Test Permission Set For Group'
    );
    insert ps2;
    //permission set group component
    PermissionSetGroupComponent psgc = new PermissionSetGroupComponent(
         PermissionSetGroupId = psg.Id,
         PermissionSetId = ps2.Id
    );
    insert psgc;
    //permission set assignment
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(
        AssigneeId = permUser.Id,
        PermissionSetId = ps.Id
    );
    insert psa;

    return permUser;
}
@isTest
private static void testGetUserPerm() {
    Test.startTest();
    List<PermissionHelper.PermInfos> permInfos = UserPermissionController.getUserPerm(testUser.Id);
    Test.stopTest();
    System.assertNotEquals(null, permInfos);
}
```